# Redeploy asp.net web api/ mvc app without iis reset

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I have an iis server that has the default website under which I run many of my asp.net web applications as applications and not virtual directories. Some of these have IOC and application cache logic that gets run through global.asax. Is there a way to redeploy one or all of these applications without doing an iis reset?

Comment: Unsure if the iis reset (the answer below covers that) is more challenging than checking to see if the sites have inter-dependencies that can potentially "break" once de-coupled (e.g. cookies, auth, and those you already mentioned - cache, sessions, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to deploy each application to IIS with it's own Application Pool.  Then when you deploy an application only the APPPool for that application the other application pools will not be reset.

Comment: Here is the command: %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe recycle <app pool identifier>